# How to color only external edges on voxels of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, voxel

I would like to draw a cube of (20,20,20) with faces of one color and edges of another color in matplotlib using voxels. But when I use the edgecolors function it takes a grid (20x20x20) and not only the edges of the cube. How can I color only the edges without the grid?
Thanks in advance.

I did the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#Create a figure
fig = plt.figure()

#Create a subplot for that figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#Define limit of axis
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.set_xlim3d(40, 110)
ax.set_ylim3d(40,110)
ax.set_zlim3d(40,110)

#Draw a cube
n_voxels = np.zeros((19, 19, 19), dtype=bool)

facecolors = np.where(n_voxels, '#FFD65DC0', '#0576EC33')
edgecolors = np.where(n_voxels, '#000000', '#000000')
filled = np.ones(n_voxels.shape)

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(x, y, z, filled, facecolors=facecolors, edgecolors=edgecolors)
```